# why asp.net website dont work after publishing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I made asp.net website, that **work well on local** (run debug in VS). But after I succesfully publish it (using VS) to a webhosting, the website does not work.

Problems started after I added references to some 3rd party DLLs and using them.

Did I miss something when referencing these DLLs?

Thank you for your time!

Error message is:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Request timed out.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.
Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:
[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4075.0
```

Comment: It looks like it timed out.

Comment: What third party dlls? If it is something commercial, it might be trying to see if it is licensed for this server, by querying their own.

Comment: Unfortunately the stack trace is empty.

Comment: it is not commercial. And it works well on local! But dont work when published :(